# Why am I getting a NameError when initializing a new Process?

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, nameerror

I am making this app using **tkinter and urllib** which is supposed to be a download manager and decided to use **multiprocessing** for each download, however, I ran into a problem. Each time that I hit the 'Download' button to get the information from my widgets to start the download, I got a **Name Error** saying that my widgets are not defined. **I tried making the widgets global and even called the widgets globally in my function and even passing them as arguments but apparently none of them worked**. I thought that it may have to do with the structure of my program so I tested it on a mock program which was much simpler and still got the same error. Why is this happening? The mock program:

```
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process

times_clicked = 0


def change_lbl():
    global times_clicked
    times_clicked += 1
    lbl.config(text=f"Clicked: {times_clicked}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")
    lbl = Label(root, text="Waiting for clicks...")

    def start():
        Process(target=change_lbl, daemon=True).start()

    btn = Button(root, text="Add to clicks...", command=start)
    lbl.pack(pady=10)
    btn.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

The error:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Family\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Family\PycharmProjects\8-bit Downloader\pyfile.py", line 10, in change_lbl
    lbl.config(text=f"Clicked: {times_clicked}")
NameError: name 'lbl' is not defined
```

Comment: tkinter widgets cannot be shared across processes.  Use threads instead.

Comment: Thank you, @acw1668 but I actually tried threading before multi-processing. The reason I switched to multi-processing was because of the `terminate()` function. I tried using events in threading for inter-communication to tell the threads when to start and stop but apparently it doesn't work with `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`. Please if you know any way that I can stop a urlretrieve thread let me know!

Comment: You can assign a callback to the `reporthook` option of `urlretrieve()`.  Inside the callback, you can raise exception based on a global flag to abort the download.  Of course you better using try/except on running `urlretrieve()`.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/EMmxMkYS) is an simple example on using `reporthook` callback to abort the download.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `lbl` write something like

```py
lbl = #something you need
```

Comment: Hello, @Oliver Hnat. Thank you for the suggestion but it seems like it does not work. I tried it and it looks like I have to redefine the entire root as well so I don't think that this is the optimal way to do so.